# MySQL: get a list of tables that references a deleted row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

Say I delete (or possibly edit) a row in a certain table. I need to get a list of all the tables that references that particular row (basically, the other tables will have a FK to the table where the row was deleted from). How do I do this? I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: Maybe it would also help to know what do you need this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this query

```
select c.table_schema,u.table_name,u.column_name,u.referenced_column_name
from information_schema.table_constraints as c
inner join information_schema.key_column_usage as u
using( constraint_schema, constraint_name )
where c.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
and u.referenced_table_schema='your_db_name'
and u.referenced_table_name = 'your_table_name'
order by c.table_schema,u.table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant (example with `sakila` db, table `actor`) -

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, referenced_table_schema, referenced_table_name
FROM
  information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE
  referenced_table_schema = 'sakila' AND referenced_table_name = 'actor'
GROUP BY
  constraint_schema, constraint_name;

+--------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| table_schema | table_name | referenced_table_schema | referenced_table_name |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| sakila       | film_actor | sakila2                 | actor                 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```